# XAMPP keeps freezing my internet

Tags: xampp, localhost

I'm creating these web pages through XAMPP but every time I go to the localhost to check what my webpage looks like Google Chrome keeps freezing.

It freezes, loads the page and then freezes again before I can actually click the webpage I want to check. I want to know is there way to stop this because it gets quite annoying especially when I'm writing a webpage for an assignment. USB WebServer has the exact same issue so I'm not sure what would be wrong with it.

Comment: If you open the default [XAMPP landing page](http://localhost/xampp/), does it freeze as well?  Have you tried other browsers?  Sharing the OS (and version) you are using might hint at the issue.

Comment: @Jerome  Yes it does freeze on the XAMPP Landing page as well on Chrome. It will eventually load but it does take about a minute or so. When I use Internet Explorer it does freeze but not as long as Chrome. The version of XAMPP I'm using is 1.8.3.

Comment: What about browsing the net while Apache is running in XAMPP?  If you were to open the landing page while also opening any random website using another tab?  Maybe this could also be a hardware issue.  Open Task Manager and see if CPU utilization spikes when you're trying to open a page on localhost.  Maybe there's a rogue process consuming all your CPU cycles.

Comment: I dunno what could be wrong with it since I can't connect to another webpage while running the landing page because the whole of Google Chrome freezes. There didn't seem to be that much change in the Task Manager. Since the highest the CPU went to was 17%.

Comment: If Chrome freezes the way you say it does, I guess it doesn't make much sense to look into Chrome Developer Tools to try and investigate the issue.  Maybe other members of the community might have an idea?